# What is the difference between SCXML statecharts and UML statecharts?

Tags: uml, state-machine, scxml

I know that the user defines them in different ways (XML compared to UML Tool), but what is the difference in semantics between the two?

Or does a statechart in SCXML mean the same thing as a comparable statechart in UML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither UML nor SCXML provide a rigorous metamodel that defines their semantics with precision; therefore, it is impossible to say whether they mean the same when they employ terms such as "state" or "transition".

SCXML states that it is based on Harel's original work, and notes that it has been implemented in UML 2.0. However, it does not claim to be semantically compatible with it.

If you are interested in semantic compatibility from a formal viewpoint, I suggest you assume very little. However, I think it is pretty safe to treat both specs as fairly equivalent regarding the core concepts for informal discussion.